# change html style with "if" condition PHP

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have mini site that displays site list I manage as a table, with expire date. I want to change color depending it's expire date.
this is html code

```
<div class="col-lg table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">title</th>
            <th scope="col">date</th>
            <th scope="col">contact person</th>
            <th scope="col">phone</th>
            <th scope="col">status</th>
            <th scope="col" >action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $button_upd = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" name="update" id="update" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">change</button>';
        foreach ($res as $rem) {
            $expire = (strtotime($rem[2]) / 86400) - (strtotime("now") / 86400);
            echo  "<tr>
                <td>" . $rem[0] . "</td>
                <td>" . $rem[1] . "</td>
                <td>" . $rem[2] . "</td>
                <td>" . $rem[3] . "</td>
                <td>" . $rem[4] . "</td>
                <td>" . $rem[5] . "</td>
                <td>" . $button_upd . "</td>                   
                </tr>";
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This code takes data from database and puts it in the table, now I want to change row color (all columns separately of course) with php if condition.
I have this code

```
    <?php
if($expire <= 30){
    echo 'expiring';
}
elseif($expire <= 0){
    echo 'expired';
}
else {
    echo 'active';
}
?>
```

and finally some css

```
.expiring{
background-color: yellow;
color: black;
}
.expired{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
.active{
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

now as I understand I need to implement my php code into HTML, as it than takes it into cycle and displays table with right colors.
can someone help with this? I can't figure out how to put this if condition in my HTML code.

Comment: as I understand I need to style <td> on all columns to gain my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in if statement you set a new variable like

```
foreach ($res as $rem) {
        $expire = (strtotime($rem[2]) / 86400) - (strtotime("now") / 86400);
        $color = ($expire <= 30) ? "expiring" : (($expire <= 0) ? "expired" : "active")
        echo  "<tr>
            <td class='". $color . "'>" . $rem[0] . "</td>
            <td>" . $rem[1] . "</td>
            <td>" . $rem[2] . "</td>
            <td>" . $rem[3] . "</td>
            <td>" . $rem[4] . "</td>
            <td>" . $rem[5] . "</td>
            <td>" . $button_upd . "</td>                   
            </tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: Yes, Yes and Yes. That's very simple, I am not very familiar to PHP and could not figure out, Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar solution.

I put a little test data in so you can see how it works

You can escape out of PHP using https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php, closing the PHP tag, for example:

```
<?php $var = 6; ?>
<p>This is <?= $var ?></p>
```

That makes it easier to mix PHP and HTML in one file, without writing a lot of `echo` statements.

Inside the `<p>` there is a short-tag - `<?= $var ?>` is the same as writing `<?php echo $var ?>`

You can also use the https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php, like so:

```
<?php if ($something) : ?>
<p>Something!</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

This allows you to create more complex HTML, without a lot of `echo`s and concatenation.

```
<?php $res =
[ 
[ 'zero0', 'one', '-2 years', 'three', 'four', 'five' ],
[ 'zero1', 'one', '+2 days', 'three', 'four', 'five' ],
[ 'zero2', 'one', '+2 months', 'three', 'four', 'five' ],
[ 'zero3', 'one', '-2 minutes', 'three', 'four', 'five' ]
];
?>

<?php foreach ($res as $rem) {
        // calculate the days to expiration
        $expire = (strtotime($rem[2]) - strtotime("now")) / 86400;

        // if the expiration date is more than 30 days in the future
        if ($expire > 30) {
                $class = 'active';
        } elseif ($expire > 0) {        // between 0 and 30
                $class = 'expiring';
        } else {                        // zero or less (expired)
                $class = 'expired';
        } ?><!-- close the PHP, use the alternate syntax -->
        <!-- put the class on the row -->
        <tr class="<?= $class ?>">      <!-- (less than)&lt;?= is a short tag -->
                <!-- print out the table cells using a loop -->
                <?php for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) : ?>
                        <td><?= $rem[$i] ?></td>
                <?php endfor ?>
                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" name="update" id="update" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">change</button></td>
        </tr>
<?php } /* close the foreach ($res ... ) */ ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I will try it.